# An 'if' condition (of any language) is read when it condition is false?

Tags: if-statement, compiler-construction

Well, is an easy question and may be a little obvious but, when a 'if' has a false condition, is it read by the compiler, or does the compiler skip it directly?

Thanks! :)

Comment: An optimizing compiler would probably throw it out since it's unreachable code.

Comment: What kind of 'if' and what language? For example, an `#if false` in C and some related languages would cause that "branch" to not even be parsed.

Comment: What does "read" mean in this case? Even if the `if` condition is false, how do expect the compiler to know about it with actually reading it?

Comment: Please read up on expression evaluation strategies: specifically, call-by-name versus call-by-value. You can find all this in books like _Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs_.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler always reads the *whole* program. If an "if" condition is met, many optimizing compilers analyze whether the condition value can be evaluated at compile time or not. If it is known at compile time, then the compiler might eliminate the condition totally from the generated code. However, if the value of the condition is not known at compile time, the compiler generates the code for evaluating the condition at runtime.

At runtime, usually conditional jump instructions are used to jump to the right piece of code, depending on the condition value. E.g. if the condition turns out to be false, the CPU will directly "jump over" the code in the if body.

Answer (score 3):

If the condition statically evaluates to false, a compiler may optimize it away.

```
if (false) {
  // The compiler may choose to drop this part from the compiled result
}
```

However, this is specific to the compiler. It is not the same across all languages and not the same across all compilers. In fact, it may depend on the optimization settings used by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In Java it is removed from the byte code during the final optimization phase. As it  an opertunity to decrease size.